# How to show a single combination from matrix of values and hide others

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Edit: I edited question, because initially classes where index based, but in real scenario they are not..

lets say I have this markup, more or less

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="room_special">
         <div class="aaaa"></div>
         <div class="bbbb"></div>
         <div class="cccc"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="room_junior">
         <div class="xyz"></div>
         <div class="ztx"></div>
         <div class="tda"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="room3">
         <div class="xxxx"></div>
         <div class="board3"></div>
         <div class="zzzzz"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I want to make visible (the rest, hidden) Room2 - Board 3, and this could change when the user clicks on some elements (not those..)

And I have two vars, which read the user events:

```
var room = 'room3';
var board = 'board3';
```

I am currently doing like this, but I think/hope that there's is a simpler way, because I have a very large number of nodes

```
function show(room,board) {
   $('.container div').fadeOut(); // hide the bothers
   $('.container div.'+room).fadeIn(); // show the one
   $('.container div .'+room+' div').fadeOut(); // hide the brothers
   $('.container div').find('.'+room+' .'+board).fadeIn(); // show the one
}
```

Now, this is working, but can I make it using a jQuery selector which I might not know or just in a single jQuery line?

EDIT2:
I can see that I could do it like this, which is a single line but actually looks worse:

```
$('.container div').not('.'+room).hide().end().filter('.'+room).show().find('div').not('.'+board).hide().end().find('.'+board).show();
```

Sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wt40focv/1)

Comment: I'm assuming what you have works. So what's the issue?

Comment: Just that, if there is a simpler/more readdable way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding some class will make it neat,

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="room room1">
         <div class="board1"></div>
         <div class="board2"></div>
         <div class="board3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="room room2">
         <div class="board1"></div>
         <div class="board2"></div>
         <div class="board3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="room room3">
         <div class="board1"></div>
         <div class="board2"></div>
         <div class="board3"></div>
    </div>
</div>

var desiredRoom = 'some-Class-That-Represent-a-room'; //populate this from button click
var desiredBoard = 'some-Class-That-Represent-a-board'; //populate this from button click

function show(desiredRoom, desiredBoard) {
  //hide all boards
  $('.room div').fadeOut();
  //show the one
  $('.' + desiredRoom +' .'+desiredBoard).fadeIn()
}
```

If we can get the classes indicating which room and board from the events [from  dropdown may be], this can work.

Comment: The thing is that I simplified a little bit my markup for the question, really the classes are not index based...

Comment: Edited the code a bit. I was not relying upon indexing, but all I need was some identification for which room and board are selected. Hope it helps @ToniMichelCaubet

Comment: +1, Thats right, I Can just hide them all, and then just show the one. But i'd have to look like this `$('.' + desiredRoom'., .' + desiredRoom +' .'+desiredBoard).fadeIn()` because the parent was hidden previously, so showing just the children it's not posible.. Agree?

Comment: No I guess. Because I am not hiding the parent (i.e. .room), I am only hiding all the divs inside room by `$('.room div').fadeOut();` By hiding all the elements inside the parent div, we are making the parent practically invisible because then it will not occupy any visible space. So, my technique 1st hides all the children and then shows only the right/required child :) @ToniMichelCaubet

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `selected` class to your shown nodes and do all of your transitions either through css or just on the `selected` class with JQuery

**JQuery**

```
$('.selected').removeClass('selected');
$('.container div.'+room).addClass('selected')
$('.container div.' +room+ '.' +board).addClass('selected')
```

**CSS** (this may need to be tweaked but its similar to what you would would end up with)

```
.selected {
   -webkit-transition: opacity 2.0s ease-in;
   -moz-transition: opacity 2.0s ease-in;
   -o-transition: opacity 2.0s ease-in;
   opacity: 1;
}
```

If you want to do the transition with jquery

```
$('.selected').fadeOut();
$('.selected').removeClass('selected');
$('.container div.'+room).addClass('selected');
$('.container div.' +room+ '.' +board).addClass('selected');
$('.selected').fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change your markup to this:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="room">
        <div class="board"></div>
        <div class="board"></div>
        <div class="board"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="room">
        <div class="board"></div>
        <div class="board"></div>
        <div class="board"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="room">
        <div class="board"></div>
        <div class="board"></div>
        <div class="board"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I would approach the problem a little differently. This removes the need to assign a unique class to each `room` and `board` element.

```
$(function() {
    $(.board).click(function() {

        // hide all the rooms except the one that
        // contains the board the user clicked
        $(.room).not($(this).parent()).fadeOut();

        // hide all the boards except the one
        // that was clicked by the user
        $(.board).not($(this)).fadeOut();

    });
});
```

Comment: It would be much easier if the click was on one of the elements, but there's a secondary event thing..

Comment: note that you missed the quotes in the selectors ;)